# Как извлечь файл из ветки, не переключаясь на эту ветку?

Tags: git

Находясь в ветке `<branch1>`, требуется извлечь файл из ветки `<branch2>`, не делая checkout.

Причем файл необходимо записать в определенную папку.

Answer (score 11):

это можно сделать, например, с помощью команды `show`:

```
$ git show ветка:путь/к/файлу
```

содержимое `файла`, находящегося в каталоге `путь/к/`, будет выведено программой *git* в *stdout*. чтобы записать этот вывод в файл `новый/путь/к/файлу`, можете воспользоваться такой примерно командой:

```
$ git show ветка:путь/к/файлу > новый/путь/к/файлу
```

---

вместо имени ветки, разумеется можно указать и имя метки и хэш коммита.

---

документация: [`man git-show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show)

идентичный вопрос на [en.so]: [View a file in a different Git branch without changing branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7856416/4827341)

Answer (score 8):

### Альтернативные варианты

#### Использовать checkout с другой рабочей областью проекта

```
mkdir -p новый/путь
git --work-tree=новый/путь checkout ветка -- путь/к/файлу
```

#### Вытащить файл в архиве и сразу его распаковать

```
git archive ветка путь/к/файлу | tar -x0 > новый/путь/к/файлу
```

Comment: осталось описать ещё вариант с `cat-file`. насколько я понимаю, это будет последний (из адекватных вопросу) вариант.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ага, я собирался добавить его попозже. Но этот путь скорее интересен "с научной точки зрения", чем для практического применения. :)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin придумал ещё один способ, через git-archive