# Как сделать push определенных файлов в git?

Tags: git, github

Вот изменил я проект и сделал сначала `git add .`, затем все закомител `git commit -m "..."` и затем пушнул в репозиторий в мастер ветку. А теперь мне нужно некоторые файлы пушнуть в другую ветку. Но как это сделать?

Comment: нельзя "пушнуть файлы в другую ветку". Но никто не мешает скопировать эти файлы, переключиться на нужную ветку, потом скопировать файлы назад в репозиторий и коммит-пуш

Comment: @KoVadim а я совсем только недавно познакомился с гит и пока не понимаю что означает "переключится на нужную ветку". Вот у меня есть проект, назовем его `project` который является мастер веткой. Что мне нужно сделать чтобы переключится в ветку `development`?

Comment: `Вот у меня есть проект, назовем его project который является мастер веткой.` эм... в котором есть ветка с именем master. Переключиться на ветку development - `git checkout development`. Это как бы базовые вещи.

Comment: @KoVadim, один раз я сел и прочел книгу по `git` но до практики дело так и не дошло. Второй раз дошло до практики и я опять прочел книгу, но сразу же оказалось что бОльшая потребность в другой области и я снова забыл что читал. Сейчас я не горю желанием садится и опять читать. День два поспрашиваю, вьеду в происходящее и затем уже прочту. 

1) И вот значит я переключился в другую ветку и добавил нужные мне файлы, закомитил их и пушнул. Так нужно работать?

Comment: 2) Как сделать так чтобы файлы из папки `project/public/*` из мастер ветки оказались в корне development ветки? Так вообще можно? То есть у меня в мастере есть папка паблик и в нем проект, который должен оказаться в gh-pages но уже как корень. Как так сделать?

Comment: @KoVadim, в одно сообщение не уместилось по этому обращаю ваше внимание на то что помимо этого сообщения вверху ещё два.

Comment: `Так нужно работать?` - а я не знаю, что Вам нужно. Но если это сделает так как надо, значит так и надо делать.

а вот второй пункт... я тут даже не совсем понимаю, что хочется сделать.

Comment: @KoVadim когда создаешь сайт на github, то создается вветка этого сайта. И вот `index.html` должен лежать в корне. Но как же тогда сделать так чтобы файлы из `project/public` оказались в другой ветки в корне? Можете сказать как это сделать а то уже голову сломал.

Comment: не вижу никаких проблем скопировать/переместить файл. обычным проводником/консолью. А потом уже добавить/удалить файлы гитом и коммит-пуш.

Comment: @KoVadim, давайте все сначала, а то то что для Вас просто, мне вообще не понятно и если я от Вас отстану, то придется задавать вопрос по новому.

У меня есть проект `project`, который открыт в `ide` и весь этот проект находится в мастер ветке. В этом проекте (я сейчас о ide) есть директория `public` с файлами которые должны лежать в другой ветке в корне.

Comment: В git я меняю ветку на нужную и пытаюсь добавить файлы открытые в ide и находящиеся в папке publec. Но git говорит что файлов нет.

Что мне нужно сделать? Проводником я не могу скопировать так как проект то открыт один и файлы там все и так есть. Предполагаю что нужно смержить, но можно ли смержить только определенную часть ветки? Можно ли изменить путь чтобы файлы из public при смерживании были в корне?

Я просто пытаюсь и понять как это сделать и понять что требовать от автоматизаторов процесса работы с git.

Это второе сообщение одного текста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После вашего пуша в мастер надо переключиться на нужную ветку `git checkout branch_name` (либо же `git checkout -b branch_name` если ветка ещё не создана), закоммитить нужные файлы `git commit file.jpg` (для каждого файла) и делать пуш нужных этих файлов `git push origin branch_name` в ветку

Comment: не получается.
`To https://github.com/**/**.git  
! [rejected]        gh-pages -> gh-pages (fetch first)  
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/**/**.git'  
подсказка: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do  
подсказка: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing  
подсказка: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes  
подсказка: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.  
подсказка: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: ну так написано же английским по белому, что этих изменений, которые пушатся, нет локально. надо запулить их себе, а потом пушить объединенные файлы куда необходимо

Answer (score 1):

> нужно некоторые файлы пушнуть в другую ветку

вообще-то «пушатся»/«пулятся» не файлы из вашего рабочего каталога («[working tree](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_working_tree)») а [объекты git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-Git) и указатели на коммиты (ветки «branches» и метки «tags»).

отсюда следует, что непосредственно с командой `push` программы *git* проблем нет: на самом деле автору вопроса надо создать и зафиксировать коммитом (в «другой ветке») некое новое состояние рабочего каталога.

исходя из ключевых слов вопроса про «**некоторые** файлы» можно сделать вывод, что простое слияние изменений из одной ветки в другую не требуется.

а требуется получить полное содержимое некоторых файлов в таком виде, как они зафиксированы коммитами в «первой» ветке (какой именно — роли не играет, главное, что это не та ветка, которая в данный момент является текущей).

в таком случае отлично подходящим дубликатом вопроса будет уже существющий: [Как извлечь файл из ветки, не переключаясь на эту ветку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/538307/178576).

краткое содержимое приведённых там ответов (три разных варианта сделать практически одно и то же):

1. `show`:

   ```
   $ git show ветка:путь/к/файлу > новый/путь/к/файлу
   ```
2. `checkout`:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p новый/путь
   $ git --work-tree=новый/путь checkout ветка -- путь/к/файлу
   ```
3. `archive`:

   ```
   $ git archive ветка путь/к/файлу | tar -x0 > новый/путь/к/файлу
   ```

а теперь уже можно делать `add` + `commit` + `push`.