# Как сохранить копию проекта в Git'е?

Tags: git

Вот такая ситуация, работаю с Git.

В проекте имплементировал несколько классов которые обрабатывают нотификацию.

Теперь оказалось, что это не нужно. Но я много времени провел над этим и хотел бы оставить себе копию того, что сейчас получилось...

Как можно сохраниться, вырезать все что не нужно, но потом если нужно чтоб можно было вернуться обратно?

Comment: Сделайте ветку, в которую положите свои изменения, где у Вас проблемы не ясно...

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V да но я не хочу волочь за собой через весь проект эту ветку... Мне не нужно, чтоб она постоянно висела... Я думал может таг поставить?

Comment: можно и таг поставить и правильно подписать его (что бы потом было понятно). А потом можно спокойно удалять изменения и продолжать кодить.

Comment: "Я думал может таг поставить?" так зачем спрашивать?)))

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V я не сильно с гитом разбираюсь. Таги ведь тоже засаряют проект если их много, думал может как то влияет...

Comment: таг стоит ровно один файл на 41 байт (40 байт хеш и перевод строки).

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/538307/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не совсем я понял что написано у вас в ответе... Как по мне это вообще другой вопрос... Мне просто нужно сохранить ветку, чтоб возмоно когда то вернуться к ней и посмотреть... А в вашем ответе о том как извлечь файлы из одной ветки в другую

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, не совсем про то, «как извлечь файлы из одной ветки в другую», а про то, как посмотреть содержимое файла по состоянию на указанный коммит. а ссылку я привёл просто для информации.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko но у в ветке отдельной ничего страшного нет. По сути это просто указатель на коммит. Абсолютно легковесная штука

Comment: @MalovVladimir да но мне висячие ветки как то визуально надоедают... Я не знаю сколько еще будет работать проект и когда мне нужно будет к этой ветке обратиться... А если я буду год работать над этим)) Это год мне смотреть на эту висячую ветку))

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. если внесённые вами изменения останутся в общем хранилище (т.е., история не будет переписана ради удаления ваших изменений), то просто запомните хэш последнего вашего коммита, чтобы позже можно было к нему вернуться:

   1. на «бумажке»;
   2. создав указатель на этот коммит (очень «лекговесная» операция — в хранилище будет создан всего один файл размером 41 байт):

      - либо фиксированный — метку (tag):

        ```
        $ git tag имя.метки коммит
        ```

        кстати, пока вы явно не укажете отправить ваши метки в общее хранилище (например, с помощью опций `--tags` или `--all` команды `push`), ваши коллеги и не узнают о их существовании: они будут храниться только в вашей локальной копии хранилища;
      - либо «плавающий» — ветку (branch):

        ```
        $ git branch имя.ветки коммит
        ```

        аналогично, пока вы явно не отправите этот указатель в общее хранилище (например, с помощью опции `--all` команды `push`, или конкретно упомянув указатель — `git push общее.хранилище имя.ветки`), ваши коллеги также не узнают о существовании этого указателя.
2. если внесённые вами изменения ещё не отправлены в общее хранилище или будут принудительно удалены из него (методом переписывания истории), вы можете создать ещё одну копию хранилища:

   1. с рабочим каталогом (т.е. со всеми файлами, история которых отслеживается):

      ```
      $ git clone /путь/к/текущему/хранилищу /путь/к/копии
      ```
   2. или без рабочего каталога (для экономии места):

      ```
      $ git clone /путь/к/текущему/хранилищу /путь/к/копии --bare
      ```
   3. или даже «пакет» (bundle):

      ```
      $ git bundle create файл.с.пакетом набор.коммитов
      ```

---

а уж как впоследствии можно будет воспользоваться сохранённым указателем или копией хранилища — «тянет» на другой, не менее многословный ответ.

Comment: Ну вот мне больше всего нравиться вариант с тагом... Во первых ветки не будут висеть, во вторых это будет подсказка только для меня... Но я верно понимаю я в любой момент могу вернуться к этому тагу так же легко как переключиться с одной ветки на другую?

Comment: и ветки (branch) и метки (tag) — это указатели на коммит. **всё** отличие между ними — метка указывает на один и тот же коммит, а ветка может сдвигаться по мере добавления коммитов.

Comment: пожалуй, про **всё** — это я перегнул палку. есть и ещё отличия. но практически все манипуляции, которые можно проделать с веткой, можно проделать и с меткой.

Comment: Вариант *"на бумажке"* обладает критическим недостатком - он не убережет коммит от сборщика мусора.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вроде это был вариант для случая, когда коммит есть в истории, а не когда он где-то в параллельной ветке, которую удалили. Хотя можно было бы явно указать это в ответе.

Comment: @Qwertiy историю могут переписать в будущем

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в ответе же написано предположение, что историю не тронут. А так-то можно и ветку, и тег удалить.

Comment: @Qwertiy ради удаления изменений - не тронут. Просто через 5 лет будут чистить репозиторий от гигабайтных контрольных бэкапов тестовой базы и сделают filter-branch :)

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд в таких случаях делается форк и сохраняется новый репозиторий, классы дорабатываются чтобы стать **библиотекой, изолированной от сильных связей с проектом**. Таким образом получаем полновесную библиотеку в копилку.

Конечно так делать нужно, если это дёшево сделать иначе следует использовать тег - но в крупных репозиториях так можно замусорить сам репозиторий и потерять тег при очередной чистке старых тегов. Тоже самое с ветками. Если разработки идёт через git flow, то постоянных веток будет только 2, остальные будут сносить после реализации фич.

p.s.
В гите нужно привыкнуть к тому, что теги легковесны, ветки легковесны, что не нужно бояться merge и не нужно бояться форков. Системы управления репозиториями вроде github, gitlab, bitbucket рассчитаны на всё это, включая форки