# Как вытащить файл из комита

Tags: git

Есть GIT. Сделали несколько комитов в репозиторий. В комитах изменялся определенный файл. Допустим у меня всего 3 комита, можно ли как-то вытащить файл из первого комита в удаленный репозиторий? Если да, то как?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как извлечь файл из ветки, не переключаясь на эту ветку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538307/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8f%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: Наверное это не то что мне надо. У меня есть master и из удаленного репозитория туда комитятся изменения. И надо из комита достать файл.

Comment: укажите хэш коммита вместо имени ветки: `$ git show хэш:путь/к/файлу` (ведь «ветка» — это всего лишь именованный указатель на коммит).

Comment: @LazyBadger Если вы такой умный, идите в другие ветки. Тут вам делать нечего! И на ты с друзьями общайся!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать update на нужный коммит и забрать файл. Если нужно сделать его текущим, то осуществить слияние с вариантом слияния "взять локальный". Либо поясните вопрос более точнее.